# $.post causes click event recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a few rows of products a customer can choose to select. These rows have the class "product-line". On the click of a row, I want to show the user that it is (un)checked by toggling the "product-checked" class, and then send a POST message with the IDs all checked rows. To do this, I wrote this code:

```js
<script>
    $(".product-line").click(onProductLineClick);

    function onProductLineClick(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("product-checked");
        updatePrice();
    }

    function updatePrice() {
        var ids = $(".product-checked")
            .map(function() {
                return $(this).data("id");
            });
        $.post("/Controller/Action", { 'productIds[]': ids });
        alert("Hi!");
    }
</script>
```

This piece of code causes the onProductLineClick to trigger indefinitely. The alert("Hi!") is never triggered. The POST is never sent.

When I remove the $.post, the click event is triggered only once and everything works fine. The toggleClass does its job, showing that the row was selected. When I do add the $.post, it all goes nuts and the moment the $.post is reached, it just fires the click event again, causing an infinite recursion.

The parameter 'e' in onProductLineClicked is never defined other than the very first time. Using e.preventDefault() causes an error on the second time it passes through there.

I'm stumped. I can't understand how or why a POST would cause the click to fire again, and remove the POST stops that from happening.

Comment: I created a fiddle for this one: https://jsfiddle.net/140w63vt/4/ I'm also getting a "too much recursion" error. I'm looking into this right now

Comment: I think it's the attempt to serialise a jQuery object (the result of .map()) which causes that. What did you intend to send in the `ids` object? I'm guessing it's not a whole jQuery array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is with your map function. There are two map functions in jQuery.

[$('element').map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) versus [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

As stated in the documentation, the first produces a new jQuery object containing the return values while the second translates all items in an array or object to new array of items.

Serialising the newly created object and passing it in an ajax request doesn't work because it has recursive references within it. [Thanks @ADyson]

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/140w63vt/14/)

```
$(".product-line").click(onProductLineClick);

function onProductLineClick(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("product-checked");
  updatePrice();
}

function updatePrice() {
  var ids = jQuery.map($(".product-checked"), function(element, index) {
      return $(element).data("id");
    });
    console.log(ids);
  $.post("/Controller/Action", {
    'productIds': ids
  });
  alert("Hi!");
}
```

Comment: it's because the other version of .map() returns a whole jQuery object, not a standard array, and serialising the object to text for including in a HTTP request doesn't work because it has recursive references within it. http://api.jquery.com/map/ . Assuming your answer produces the `ids` data in the format the server is expecting then this is probably the right alternative.

Comment: You are correct. There are two map functions. I will try to explain my answer correctly. Thank you

Comment: Yep, that was it! I was too tunnel visioned on the fact that the $.post line caused it to realize that the serializing of the ids actually caused the issue.

So I used the wrong map. I changed it to $.map and it's all good now. Thanks!